# Can't connect to Neo4j db in my ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, neo4j

I have problem while connecting to my neo4j database.

This is my code:

```
private GraphClient client;

    public Neo4j()
    {
        client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/mydb"), "neo4j", "123");

        client.Connect();
    }
```

And this is the error I get when I try to connect:

> Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.
>   The response status was: 404 Not Found
>   The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: " .

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: which libray are you using ? (I don't know what is your `GraphClient`) . Moreover are you sure of your URL  ? The  `mydb` at the end seems a little weird for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using this library : https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient

Your Neo4j url is wrong, you should use this one instead : `GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));`

Comment: Yap you are right. That was my mistake. When i read their document i saw it.